# dynamically pass string to Rscript argument with sed

Tags: r, bash, sed

I wrote a script in R that has several arguments. I want to iterate over 20 directories and execute my script on each while passing in a substring from the file path as my -n argument using sed. I ran the following:

```
find . -name 'xray_data' -exec sh -c 'Rscript /Users/Caitlin/Desktop/DeMMO_Pubs/DeMMO_NativeRock/DeMMO_NativeRock/R/scipts/dataStitchR.R -f {} -b "{}/SEM_images" -c "{}/../coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|SEM|Os" -d "overview" -y "overview" --overview "overview.*tif" -p FALSE -n "`sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/' "{}"`"' sh {} \;
```

which results in this error:

```
ubs/DeMMO_NativeRock/DeMMO_NativeRock/R/scipts/dataStitchR.R -f {} -b "{}/SEM_images" -c "{}/../coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|SEM|Os" -d "overview" -y "overview" --overview "overview.*tif" -p FALSE -n "`sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/' "{}"`"' sh {} \;
sh: command substitution: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: command substitution: line 0: `sed -e s/.*DeMMO.*[/](.*)_.*[/]xray_data/1/ "./DeMMO1/D1T3rep_Dec2019_Ellison/xray_data"'
```

When I try to use sed with my pattern on an example file path, it works:

```
echo "./DeMMO1/D1T1exp_Dec2019_Poorman/xray_data" | sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/'
```

which produces the correct substring:

```
D1T1exp_Dec2019
```

I think there's an issue with trying to use single quotes inside the interpreted string but I don't know how to deal with this. I have tried replacing the single quotes around the sed pattern with double quotes as well as removing the single quotes, both result in this error:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

How should I extract the substring from the file path dynamically in this case?

Comment: That will be almost too complicated with embedding a command using -exec using find, since, yeah it will be a quoting hell ;-) A better alternative is to loop through the files by parsing the output of `find`,  just  my two cents.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @Jetchisel ! I will try to figure out a for loop solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that ultimately worked for me due to issues with quotes in sed:

```
for dir in `find . -name 'xray_data'`; 
do sampleID="`basename $(dirname $dir) | cut -f1 -d'_'`";
Rscript /Users/Caitlin/Desktop/DeMMO_Pubs/DeMMO_NativeRock/DeMMO_NativeRock/R/scipts/dataStitchR.R -f "$dir" -b "$dir/SEM_images" -c "$dir/../coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|SEM|Os" -d "overview" -y "overview" --overview "overview.*tif" -p FALSE -n "$sampleID"; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the output of find.

```sh
while IFS= read -ru "$fd" -d '' files; do
  echo "$files"  ##: do whatever you want to do with the files here.
done {fd}< <(find . -type f -name 'xray_data' -print0)
```

- No embedded commands in quotes.
- It uses a random `fd` just in case something inside the loop is eating/slurping `stdin`
- Also `-print0` delimits the files with `null` bytes, so it should be safe enough to handle spaces tabs and newlines on the path and file names.
- A good start is always put an `echo` in front of every commands you want to do with the files, so you have an idea what's going to be executed/happen just in case...

Comment: thanks for your help here, I'm still running into trouble with sed though! I tried this:  while IFS= read -r files; do
  Rscript /Users/Caitlin/Desktop/DeMMO_Pubs/DeMMO_NativeRock/DeMMO_NativeRock/R/scipts/dataStitchR.R -f "$files" -b "$files/SEM_images" -c "$files/../coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|SEM|Os" -d "overview" -y "overview" --overview "overview.*tif" -p FALSE -n "sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/' "$files""
done < <(find . -name 'xray_data') which produces: sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/' ./DeMMO1/D1T1exp_Dec2019_Poorman/xray_data

Comment: I also tried running the line above but with: -n "`sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/' "$files"`" instead, which results in the error "illegal byte sequence", If I include print0 I don't see any of my console output which I need in order to debug the script.

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong: Caitlins-MacBook-Pro-2:data Caitlin$ while IFS= read -ru "$fd" -d '' files; do
>     Rscript /Users/Caitlin/Desktop/DeMMO_Pubs/DeMMO_NativeRock/DeMMO_NativeRock/R/scipts/dataStitchR.R -f "$files" -b "$files/SEM_images" -c "$files/../coordinates.txt" -z ".tif" -m ".tif" -a "Unknown|SEM|Os" -d "overview" -y "overview" --overview "overview.*tif" -p FALSE -n "`sed -e 's/.*DeMMO.*[/]\(.*\)_.*[/]xray_data/\1/' "$files"`"
> done {fd}< <(find . -name 'xray_data' -print0)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{fd}'

Comment: Right, if you're bash not recent enough that will be a problem.

Comment: remove the `"$fd"` and `{fd}` also make sure you're using `bash` and not `sh`

Comment: Also `-ru` to `-r`

Comment: ok thanks, I am back to my issue in my first comment here then, sed is still giving me trouble